# Invalid expression term 'string' error in event and delegates

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Using event and delegates I have tried this.

```
public delegate void ColourChangerAction(string str);
public static event ColourChangerAction OnClicked;
void OnGUI() { 
            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2, Screen.height-200, 50,50),texture1)){
                if (OnClicked != null) {
                    OnClicked(string strr);///error here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                }
            }
```

but it is showing me the error Invalide expression term string. If I don't provide string pararmenter then it shows does not take 0 arugements.

well I'm new to delegates and events. what I'm missing.??

while in another class I am doing this for getting event call.

```
 EventManager.OnClicked += ColourChanger;//registering 
 public void ColourChanger(string colourName)
    {
        print("Colour Changer " + colourName);
        if (colourName == "Red")
        {
            print(gameObject.name);
            hitInfo.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.red;
        }
        else if (colourName == "Green")
        {
            print(gameObject.name);
            hitInfo.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.green;
        }
        else if (colourName == "Yellow")
        {
            print(gameObject.name);
            hitInfo.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color = Color.yellow;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register that event

```
 OnClickedE += new ColourChangerAction(OnGUI);
```

You have to re-define the methode signature for subscribe this event.

```
void OnGUI(string str)
{
    if (1 == 1)
    {
        if (OnClickedE != null)
        {
            //  OnClicked(string strr);///error here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        }
    }
}
```

Hence your Whole code will be like the following:

```
//Defining Delegate and event
public delegate void ColourChangerAction(string str);
public static event ColourChangerAction OnClicked;
// Method signature for subscribe the event
   static void OnGUI(string str)
   {
    if (1 == 1)
    {
        if (OnClickedE != null)
        {
           // perform your action here
        }
    }
   }
//register the event 
OnClicked += new ColourChangerAction(OnGUI);
// Invoke the event dynamically
 OnClicked.DynamicInvoke("Some string");
```

Update:

In your case please replace the code `OnClicked(string strr);` with

```
OnClicked.DynamicInvoke("red");// pass the color here
```

Comment: You can now check the updates in the answer for solution

Answer (score 0):

1) Do not use static events.

[*Negative Aspects/Bad Practice of Static Event in C#*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16339848/negative-aspects-bad-practice-of-static-event-in-c-sharp)

2) Use [Event Design](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229011(v=vs.100).aspx)

*Do use System.EventHandler instead of manually creating new delegates to be used as event handlers.*

[Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Counter c = new Counter( ... );
    c.ThresholdReached += c_ThresholdReached;
    ...
}

static void c_ThresholdReached(object sender, ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The threshold of {0} was reached at {1}.", e.Threshold,  e.TimeReached);
    ...
}


class Counter
{
    ...
    public void Add(int x)
    {
        total += x;
        if (total >= threshold)
        {
            ThresholdReachedEventArgs args = new ThresholdReachedEventArgs();
            args.Threshold = threshold;
            args.TimeReached = DateTime.Now;
            OnThresholdReached(args);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnThresholdReached(ThresholdReachedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Thread safe event
        EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> handler = ThresholdReached;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> ThresholdReached;
}

public class ThresholdReachedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Threshold { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeReached { get; set; }
}
```